# React-Router path with parameters displaying properly in development but not in production

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a very simple react app, basically i want to display a page from a link with parameters and i display the parameters in the page.

The funny thing is it renders properly in development and when I run "npm run build" and I just copy it on a subfolder in the root folder in CPanel.

Also if I completely remove the  tags and just show  then my page displays but values displayed are not dynamic.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

I have the following code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Voucher from './Voucher';

import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path="/gift/:id4" component={Voucher} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
      {/* <Voucher /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Voucher.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import '../components/App.css';

class Voucher extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="header-logo">
          <img className="logo" src={require('../img/vouch_logo.png')} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="voucher-body">
          <div className="voucher-text">Gift Voucher</div>
          <div className="voucher-amt">
            SAR {parseInt(this.props.match.params.id4, 10)}
          </div>
          <div className="voucher-num">
            12345678
          </div>
          <div className="footer-text">
            <a href=""></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Voucher;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vouchers",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://www.besidegroup.com/gift",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Update for clarity:

I get a blank page if i just navigate to www.mypage.com/gift.  Inspect shows that it is navigating to the correct index.html, and it just shows the  tags.

However, when I try to navigate with the parameter www.mypage.com/gift/1 I get 404 error not found.

Update:

I changed the Route path from

```
<Route path="/gift/:id4" component={Voucher} />
```

to

```
<Route path="/:id4" component={Voucher} />
```

I navigate again to www.mypage.com/gift and at least it displays the page but its shows NaN error on the displayed text since it is not passing any variable. However, when I navigate to www.mypage.com/gift/1 I get another 404 error not found.

Comment: Nothing displays at all in production? Do you get a blank page? Errors in the console? React dev tools give you anything? A little more details would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just replicated your question with this route `<Route path="/:id4" component={Voucher} />` .... if i navigated to `http://localhost:3000/gifts/433` the value of SAR gives NAN because this is not the defined path...

But if if i navigated to `http://localhost:3000/433` it gives the url value right.

Also i think you are deploying your react app incorrectly....you cannot just copy the `build` folder to your Cpanel......React applications is built on node, and cannot be copied to Cpanel.

There is a lot of options to where to deploy you app..like Heroku, Digital ocean or AWS or a lot other... Almost all of them offer free tier for learning...and here is a one of many [tutorials](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-how-to-deploy-a-production-react-app-to-heroku-c4831dfcfa08) out there to start with

Comment: Thanks @Ahm.  Actually both `<Route path="/:id4" component={Voucher} />` and `<Route path="/gift/:id4" component={Voucher} />` worked in development.  I googled a bit more and it seems that **Cpanel does not support Node yet**, which is maybe why the passing of the params through the pathing did not work.  Anyway, I just deployed through Heroku and redirected from my /gift url.